# Open LDAP - How to get a more specific error response code if 'Invalid Credentials' error is encountered?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, openldap

More specifically, how do we distinguish between 'bad password' and 'password expired' case with an Open LDAP server (if we are using Microsoft Active Directory, the 'Invalid Credentials' error has a more specific error response code like 525 or 532 that can be used to differentiate)?

Comment: It's generally considered poor security to do this. If you tell the user his password was incorrect you have also told him he was using a valid userID, which makes cracking the system much easier.

Comment: I agree, but is there a way to do it?

Comment: Not unless OpenLDAP returns some indication in the response.

Comment: Agree with @EJP. Populating the BIND result diagnostic message is a terrible idea unless the server is hidden behind other software that interprets the diagnostics and its transmissions are encrypted. It is extremely unwise and a poor security practice to transmit information regarding the state of an account, or whether the account exists at all. This is pretty basic security stuff.

Comment: Hmmm, I wonder why Microsoft AD provides that option then...if its a basic security flaw.